# A set of typefaces that cover the whole Unicode character range

Tags: unicode, fonts

Does anybody know a set of typefaces that altogether cover the whole Unicode character range? we know that it is impossible to display all unicode characters using just one or two fonts. But probably, we can find a set of fonts using them the whole Unicode range could be displayed. Does anybody have any experience?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: @bmargulies--I have heard it's not possible for a font to cover the entire Unicode (for some technical reason). But, if you know one, please do tell us what it is.

Comment: @Craig McQueen - I don't believe there's a technical barrier, but I also don't see any evidence that the giant Unicode 2000+ font was ever updated to current inventory.

Answer (score 3):

One way to find such set of fonts is to look into [Windows Font Linking](http://www.siao2.com/2005/10/01/476022.aspx). If you take a look at the registry key HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontLink\SystemLink you'll see fonts that "link" to cover the complete Unicode set.

Answer (score 0):

Everson Mono covers a large portion of the Unicode characters, and SIL International makes a lot of different fonts for minority languages.